# Google Apps Script Redirect to an HTML file after successful log in on firebase

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, firebase-authentication

Hello I am kinda new in using google apps script.

Login.html

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {        
    window.location = home.html;}
```

After successful log-in I want to redirect it to home.html The error I am getting is

```
firebase.js:1 ReferenceError: home is not defined
at Object.next (userCodeAppPanel:84)
at firebase.js:1
at firebase.js:1
```

I also have tried to use this method:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {        
    window.location = https://script.google.com/.../dev?page=home; }
```

but doesn't work either anyway methods to try out?

Edited** thanks to raphaelSeguin I forgot the quotation in the link.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {        
    window.location = 'https://script.google.com/.../dev?page=home'; }
```

Error now is:

```
Refused to display 'https://script.google.com/xxxx/dev?page=home' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Put the URL inside quotation marks
- Since the page is served in a iframe, use `window.top` to change the top location.

  ```
  window.top.location = 'https://script.google.com/.../dev?page=home;';
  ```

Comment: Refused to display 'https://script.google.com/a/xxx/dev?page=home' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

Comment: then it's a CORS problem now.